# Xamarin TimePicker Fragment Dialog

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin, android-timepicker

I'm working on a Xamarin Android app in C#, and I'm trying to implement a TimePicker dialog, in which the user chooses a given time, and they will be notified every day (or the days in the week that he chooses).

I understand There is a TimePickerDialog Control that was deprecated, and that we need to use now a Fragment Dialog. If anyone can help me, I'd very much appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is sample code from project:

```
class TimePickerFragment : DialogFragment
{
    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return new TimePickerDialog(Activity, (sender, args) =>
        {
            //args contains new time
        }, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Giorgi, see my comment above.

Comment: @amitairos: What issue do you have? This code is already in C#

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just didn't quite understand the code. I'll try it when I'll get the chance to. What does Bundle mean? Thanks.

Comment: @Giorgi You should probably reference where `MvxDialogFragment` comes from for newer developers.

Comment: @JonDouglas: I thought the question was about MvvmCross, I'll remove that.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would be to extend `DialogFragment` and create your own `TimePickerFragment` from it. Android even has a whole doc on the topic:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#TimePicker

(**Note:** You will have to convert the respective Java -> C# but that shouldn't be too much of an issue)

```
public class TimePickerFragment : DialogFragment, TimePickerDialog.IOnTimeSetListener
{
    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Calendar c = Calendar.Instance;
        int hour = c.Get(CalendarField.HourOfDay);
        int minute = c.Get(CalendarField.Minute);
        return new TimePickerDialog(Activity, this, hour, minute, DateFormat.Is24HourFormat(Activity));
    }

    public void OnTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
    {
        //Do something when time chosen by user
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon.. I'm not very experienced in programming, so I don't really know how to convert it to C#, and specifically to Xamarin. I found this https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/fragment/select_a_date_in_a_fragment/ on their site, but it's just for a DatePicker dialog, and I didn't succeed in implementing it to a TimePicker. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out when I'll get the chance to.

Comment: @JonDouglas - Can I disable hours in time picker?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of how I implemented the TimePickerDialog

1. Declare the EditText Control (you can just use a TextView)

   EditText startTimeInput = FindViewById(Resource.Id.newEventStartTimeInput);
2. Create a TimePickerFragment by extending the DialogFragment and handle OnCreate and OnTimeSet methods

   ```
   //Time Picker
   public class TimePickerFragment : DialogFragment, 
                             TimePickerDialog.IOnTimeSetListener
   {
       // TAG can be any string of your choice.
       public static readonly string TAG = "Y:" + typeof(TimePickerFragment).Name.ToUpper();

       // Initialize this value to prevent NullReferenceExceptions.
       Action<TimeSpan> _timeSelectedHandler = delegate { };

       public static TimePickerFragment NewInstance(Action<TimeSpan> onTimeSet)
       {
           TimePickerFragment frag = new TimePickerFragment();
           frag._timeSelectedHandler = onTimeSet;
           return frag;
       }

       public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           Calendar c = Calendar.Instance;
           int hour = c.Get(CalendarField.HourOfDay);
           int minute = c.Get(CalendarField.Minute);
           bool is24HourView = true;
           TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(Activity,
                                                          this,
                                                          hour,
                                                          minute,
                                                          is24HourView);
           return dialog;
       }

       public void OnTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
       {
           //Do something when time chosen by user
           TimeSpan selectedTime = new TimeSpan(hourOfDay, minute, 00);
           Log.Debug(TAG, selectedTime.ToString());
           _timeSelectedHandler(selectedTime);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Show Fragment

   ```
       private void StartTimeInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       TimePickerFragment frag = TimePickerFragment.NewInstance(delegate (TimeSpan time)
       {
           startTimeInput.Text = time.ToString();
       });
       frag.Show(FragmentManager, TimePickerFragment.TAG);
   }
   ```

Hope this helps!